# Adding Multiple Markers on Vue JS Google Maps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I have Google Maps embedded on Vue JS code. But I want to show multiple markers using latitude and longitude on that map. Any idea on how to do that?
Here is my code.

```
Maps.vue

<template>
    <card type="plain" title="Google Maps">
      <div id="map" class="map">
      </div>
    </card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    let myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(40.748817, -73.985428);
    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: myLatlng,
      scrollwheel: false, //we disable de scroll over the map, it is a really annoing when you scroll through page
      styles: [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#1d2c4d"
        }]
      },
        {
          "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#8ec3b9"
          }]
        },
        {
          "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#1a3646"
          }]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "water",
          "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
          "stylers": [{
            "color": "#4e6d70"
          }]
        }
      ]
    };
    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map"),
      mapOptions
    );

    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title: "Hello World!"
    });

   
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
};
</script>
```

How can I display multiple markers on this google map? Any advice or tips would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [gmap-vue](https://diegoazh.github.io/gmap-vue/#about-gmapvue) plugin for VueJS to add multiple markers by clicking on the map.

First, initialize your Google Map, and make sure to add an array of `markers: []` that will contain all the markers that you will be adding on the map:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <gmap-map
      :center="center"
      ref="mmm"
      :zoom="12"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px"
      @click="addMarker"
    >
      <gmap-marker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      />
    </gmap-map>
  </div>
</template>


export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  data() {
    return {
      center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
      markers: [],
    };
  },
  
};
```

You can add markers by calling the `@click="addMarker"` event on `<gmap-map>`. Then, on the your methods you can add the `addMarker(event)` function where you should be able to get the click coordinates from the map. You can now

Here is what it looks like:

```
methods: {
    addMarker(event) {
      const marker = {
        lat: event.latLng.lat(),
        lng: event.latLng.lng(),
      };
      console.log(marker);
      this.markers.push({ position: marker });
      this.$refs.mmm.panTo(marker);
      //this.center = marker;
  },
},
```

Here is a working codesandbox for your reference, just put your API key on the `main.js` file: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-fast-b41ps

Answer (score 0):

You can use- but you don't need any plug-in. It doesn't really save time in this use-case imho.

With the standard implementation it would look something like that:

```
this.yourPOIs.forEach(poi => {
    var myLatLng = { lat: poi.latitude, lng: poi.longitude };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: this.myMap,
        title: poi.annotation
        // you can also add data here with key names that are not in use like for example "uuid: 1" so you can access that data later on if you click on markers or iterate through them
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log(marker.uuid); // if you want to react on clicking on a marker
    });
    this.addedMarkers.push(marker);
});
```

myMap being the map object written in a local variable instead of writing it in a let-variable (you will probably need to access the map later on so you better safe them in the local data of the component or your vuex store).

That's also why i pushed the markers in an array of the component. By that you can later on do this to delete the markers again (for e.g. updating the map):

```
this.addedMarkers.forEach(marker => {
     marker.setMap(null);
});
```